# What to replace raring-backports?

Tags: updates

I got problems when do any updating. The problem is the raring-backports is not available on http://ftp.iinet.net.au:

```
Err http://ftp.iinet.net.au raring-backports/main amd64 Packages                
  404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.iinet.net.au raring-backports/restricted amd64 Packages          
  404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.iinet.net.au raring-backports/universe amd64 Packages            
  404  Not Found
Get: 18 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [5,636 B]            
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_AU                      
Err http://ftp.iinet.net.au raring-backports/main i386 Packages                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.iinet.net.au raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.iinet.net.au raring-backports/universe i386 Packages             
  404  Not Found
```

For this reason, I got these error messages:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages: 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages: 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages: 404  Not Found`
```

I checked on my web browser that these URLs don't exist. So anyone knows what other repos can replace them?

Maybe good to let you know that I'm using lubuntu 14.04:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

And the relevant line in source.list:

```
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raring-backports` is for Ubuntu 13.04 "Raring Ringtail" so you don't need it any more.

For 14.04 it's `trusty-backports`:

```
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe
```

If you already have an entry for `trusty-backports` you may just remove the line for `raring-backports`

Comment: Thanks Florian! My problem solved! I got that problem when I updated aptitude. I don't why in my source.list it's raring-backports intead of trusty-backports, though I am using 14.04.